# Difference between 「来ませんでした」and「来なかったです」

Tags: politeness, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is じゃないです equally correct as じゃありません?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/is-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-equally-correct-as-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)

Both have the same meaning ("did not come") and according to my Japanese co-workers both are acceptable while they can't define the difference.

What is the (possibly obscure) difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same question, but the answer applies as well:

[Is じゃないです equally correct as じゃありません?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/is-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-equally-correct-as-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)

Comment: When you find a duplicate question like this, you should not create an individual answer but vote to close the question and give the link to the duplicate question. If you do not have enough reputations to vote to close, you can still comment to the question providing the link to the duplicate question.

Comment: @sawa, As I said, the question was not duplicate, the answer was. Otherwise, we would have to change the original question to be general enough to encompass this question as well.

Comment: You can still tell that the question is a related one, if not a duplicate, and vote to close.