# When is "私じゃ" used?

Tags: particles

One of my Japanese friends wrote this sentence:

> 私**じゃ**歌えない

She meant that she can't sing a particular song. Is じゃ used in that sentence the same way が would be used to put an emphasis on the subject, or is there a different meaning to it?

Also, how informal is this form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [上手ではありません or 上手じゃありません](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27348/%e4%b8%8a%e6%89%8b%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93-or-%e4%b8%8a%e6%89%8b%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; this is about topic marking with じゃ/では.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「[私]{わたし}**じゃ**[歌]{うた}えない。」

＝

> 「私**では**歌えない。」

「じゃ」 is the colloquial contraction of 「では」.  More importantly, this 「では/じゃ」 placed directly after the subject of a sentence is quite ***nuanced***.  Therefore, the plain and neutral 「は」 cannot replace it for the nuance.

It means that the subject (「私」 in this case) is ***not good enough to do something for some reason***.

**"I could not sing (this song), (but some other people probably could)"**

**"I am not good enough to sing (this particular song)."**

[image]
<sub>(source: [smilevideo.jp](http://tn-skr1.smilevideo.jp/smile?i=24855504.L))</sub>

「[僕]{ぼく}じゃダメですか？」 = "Am I not good enough for you?"