# What does あなたでは mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-で

I was studying the grammar for かもしれない and I found the following example:

> あなた**では**間に合わないかもしれない。

The translation given for this sentence is...

> "You might not get there in time."

And then I got confused 'cause I thought that the meaning was:

> "He might not be with you on time"

why? Because of the で particle since it could also mean "with" (with you, with him, etc.) But maybe the person who wrote this put that で by mistake.
Because I can't understand what で does in this sentence.
Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30382/9831

Answer (score 0):

Considering just the bare sentence and your given translation, I would think of something like:

> あなたでは間に合わないかもしれない。　You might not get there in time "by yourself".