# Negation with ではありません vs. じゃない

Tags: grammar

I tried to say "I'm not a high school student". But I read you can use じゃない to 'deny' something. In this case which one should I use? ではありません or じゃない?

私{わたし}はこうこうの学生{がくせい}ではありません。or  私{わたし}はこうこうの学生{がくせい}じゃないです。?

Comment: Pure translation questions are not acceptable here, sorry. Please try to ask a more substantive question about where it is you're having trouble. Is it a vocabulary problem? Grammar?

Comment: Sorry! I just edit my question and now I think it's a valid one.

Comment: You could maybe say [高校生](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%AB%98%E6%A0%A1%E7%94%9F&ref=sa) instead of こうこうの学生.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, you would use で**は**, not で**わ**.  It's the particle `は`, the same one as `私は` at the beginning of your sentence.

Second, you have many options here.  `じゃ` is just a contraction of `では`, and `ない` is just the informal form of `ありません`.  So you have four choices that are all correct.

> - じゃない　→　most informal
> - ではない
> - じゃありません
> - ではありません　→　most formal

So it really depends on the context, who you're speaking to, and how formal you want to be.  Whether or not you want to say `では・じゃないです` instead of just `では・じゃない` is another issue, but you may want to [look at this topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2574/78) regarding that.