# Is no the same as not?

Tags: words, usage, hiragana

is いいえ/no the same as not? For example, if I said,いいえ  きょう, would that mean Not Today? Or No Today? I know google translate is known to be inaccurate, but it shows both Not and No as the same, いいえ. Sorry if this is kind of a dumb question, but I'm getting kind of confused. The language app I use to learn is Drops if that helps, and I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means "No". "Not Today" would be 今日じゃないです or 今日ではありません. (Keep in mind that sentence structures are quite different from English.)

Comment: thank you, I am very new to learning, and I dont know much at all about structuring, or punctuation, just speaking.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your premise about いいえ not entirely correct.  いいえ does not translate directly to English ***no***; it really means what amounts to ***negative*** or ***opposite***.  So while most of the time that *can* directly translate to ***no***, it "naturally" translates to English ***yes*** when the preceding question is negative (and similarly for はい).

> A: おい、[今日]{きょう}[公園]{こう・えん}に[行]{い}きますか:   Hey, are you going to the park today?
> B: いいえ、行きません:   No (I'm not going)—sounds fine in English.

> A: 今日公園に[行きません]{not going}か:  Aren't you going to the park today?
>
> Natural English (what we'd say)　→　Japanese →　Literal English (what it means)
>
> - You ***aren't*** going:   "**No**, I am not going"　→　 「**はい**、行きません」　→　Yes/Affirmative/Correct, I am [not going]{行きません}
> - You ***are*** going:   "**Yeah**, I am going"　→　「**いいえ**、行きます」　→　"No/Negative/Incorrect (I am not [not going]{行きません}), I **am** going"

So its meaning is directly tied to the actual verb form used.

So now knowing a broader meaning of いいえ, you can see that it cannot be applied to "not today".  As @Vue said, it has to be [今日じゃない or 今日ではありません](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12846/78) ("(it is) not today").