# How does the negative work in this sentence: 家は綺麗じゃないではありません。

Tags: grammar, usage, negation

I tried to use several language translation websites and they all gave me different results. Some say "家は綺麗じゃないではありません” means '**the house is not clean**', but some say "家は綺麗じゃないではありません” means that '**it's not that the house is not clean**.' Which would you say is correct? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind sharing where you found the sentence?

Comment: It's a sentence that I found in my Japanese notes. I'm not sure about where the source is now. sorry

Comment: I'd think what the note meant is ではありません as an alternative to じゃない. Related [Negation with ではありません vs. じゃない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12846)

Comment: Thank you, I've read the answers to that question but I am trying to see if　じゃない 　and  ではありません　can be used together in the same sentence and if they negate each other.

Comment: The only scene I can imagine where this sentence makes any sense is a mother reproving her child for saying the house is not clean.

Comment: Would this make more sense if it said 家は綺麗じゃないって言う訳ではない... ? Assuming the sentence continues with a clause that contradicts the first one? Perhaps claiming it's not exactly spotless either?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence 家は綺麗じゃないではありません is incorrect. You can say 家は綺麗じゃなくはありません (colloquial) or 家は綺麗でなくはありません. Both of them mean the house isn't not clean.

Tho even with the correct structure it doesn't sound very natural (it's not wrong but it seems like an uncommon phrasing). I think most people would say 家汚くはないです