# では vs でも, vs じゃ what is the difference?

Tags: meaning, usage, nuances

Kind of a japanese newb here.  I've googled this a bit and haven't seen anything except demo vs temo comparisons.  I understood that these words all kind of mean "but, well, so, anyways"....am I way off base on this?  And if not, what are the subtleties or grammar rules governing each one?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/is-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-equally-correct-as-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93

Answer (score 1):

「じゃ」is colloquial form of 「では」.

I think it's no easy to explain here...

「では」emphasises, for example: 「東京**では**物価は高い」. This means, prices (costs) are in expensive in Tokyo, having in mind than it's cheaper in other cities.

「でも」: Let's say you can accomplish 1 task in 2 different ways. Method 1 is better than method 2, but it's achievable with method 2 as well. So you can use 「でも」as follows. Method 2**でも**できる。I would translate 「でも」as 「as well」or 「as well as」.

Hope this helps.