# What is the difference between ではありません and 〜くない

Tags: grammar, syntax

I am not sure when ではありません and 〜くない are used.
I was given the sentence この赤いかばんは大きいではありません (as in "this red bag is not big") and I am not sure why この赤いかばんは大きくないです was not used. Could anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: 大きいではありません does not seem grammatically correct to me, 大きくありません would be grammatically correct. I believe ありません is a step of politeness over ないです。 Actually this probably answers your question better than me https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/is-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-equally-correct-as-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93

Comment: 〜くない (and くありません) attaches to い adjectives, while ではありません (and ではない) attaches to nouns and な adjectives

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is じゃないです equally correct as じゃありません?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/is-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-equally-correct-as-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)

Answer (score 1):

> この赤いかばんは大きいではありません

Are you sure this is the sentence you saw and that it came from a reputable source?

The sentence does **not** mean "This red bag is not big". As you correctly pointed out, the correct way to say that would be この赤いかばんは大きくありません or この赤いかばんは大きくないです etc.

You cannot negate an i-adjective by adding ではありません, ではない、じゃない etc, after the adjective.

This sentence has the opposite meaning of "This red bag is big, isn't it?", but expressed rather formally. [This link](http://maggiesensei.com/2013/02/13/how-to-use-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-janai%E3%80%80%EF%BC%86%E3%80%80%E3%80%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-njanai/) may be helpful.